# "from PIL import Image" getting error when double click running script

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to run a script by double clicking the .py file but it is crashing. When I run the script in the code editor it goes fine, but when double clicking it seemns to crash after the line:

```
from PIL import Image
```

I know that because I inserted `input("Press Enter to exit)` around the script to check where it crashes, as if follows:

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

input("Press Enter to exit")
from PIL import Image
input("Press Enter to exit")

chrome_options = Options()
```

So I can see that after the first "Enter" it crashes, before getting to the second "Enter". Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you call _it is crashing_? Is there an error message?

Comment: Maybe your default python environments in the editor and outside are not the same, hence running the script outside your editor uses a python environment that does not have PIL installed. Do you use any special python package manager like Anaconda or virtualenv?

Comment: @Arnaud there is no error message, the python window just closes after the first "Enter", without waiting for the second "Enter". Yes, I'm using the IntelliJ as editor, is there any how I can check if they are using the same environment?

Comment: Do you mean Pycharm? (and not IntelliJ)

Comment: @Arnaud That was it, the environments in the editor and outside were not the same, after you said, I reinstalled everything again to ensure it was going to be at the same environments, and it worked, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Cool! No problem.